# ZF2 How I can do a session echo in my view?

Tags: zend-framework, view, zend-framework2

Do you how I can do to print a session variable in my view as:

```
<?php echo $this->session->user_id; ?>
```

Thanks you very much !

Edit:

To call a session variable in your view, you have to use this code:

```
$session = new \Zend\Session\Container('session_key');
echo $session->user_id;
```

Comment: Since you are new here, please take [a tour](http://stackoverflow.com/tour) to figure this site out.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

try

```
$session = new \Zend\Session\Container('session_key');
echo $session->user_id;
```